# html onclick to load external javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, external

I am trying to load an external javascript from a html input button. However when I click on the button I get no output or response. I do get a message in console that the script has been loaded though. 
HTML:

```
<div class="split left">
    <fieldset class="Receiver Commands">
        <legend>Receiver Commands</legend>
<input type="button" value="click me" id="clickMe" onclick="serverStart()" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{%static 'scripts/ServerResponse.js' %}">
    </script>
            <form method="post">
            </form>
        <div id="testtaskbox" class="testtaskbox">
        {% csrf_token %}

        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="receiverResponse">
        <legend>Receiver Response</legend>
        <div class="receiverText">
            <textarea id ="response" class="textarea">Digdebugv2 1.11
                {{responseContext}}
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
serverStart()
function serverStart () {
  document.getElementById('reponse').innerHTML = '123bob'
  console.log('ServerResponse started')
}
```

Comment: Check console for error

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you are trying to get `reponse` instead of `response` when your are using `getElementById`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `document.getElementById('reponse').innerHTML = '123bob'`
'response' was not correct spelled.

Replace your current code with this and it will work.

```js
 function serverStart () {
  document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = '123bob'
  console.log('ServerResponse started')
}
serverStart();
```

```html
    <div class="split left">
     <fieldset class="Receiver Commands">
      <legend>Receiver Commands</legend>
    <input type="button" value="click me" id="clickMe" onclick="serverStart()" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{%static 'scripts/ServerResponse.js' %}">
     </script>
       <form method="post">
       </form>
      <div id="testtaskbox" class="testtaskbox">
      {% csrf_token %}
    
      </div>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset class="receiverResponse">
      <legend>Receiver Response</legend>
      <div class="receiverText">
       <textarea id ="response" class="textarea">Digdebugv2 1.11
        {{responseContext}}
       </textarea>
      </div>
     </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh my god, im an idiot. been looking at this for hours, thank you!

Comment: no problem. please set question as answered. that way everyone knows the question is answered. @Callum